# Can't Transfer Amount to Connect Stripe Account

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

**BackGround:**

What i'm trying to do is set-up a marketplace where the customer can acquire services of a seller,The Project is a MERN Stack Travel Application to be exact. What i would like is for the customer to Pay the Platform(*My Website connected with Stripe*) when he wishes to acquire a service e.g a hotel Room. The Customer stays at the hotel for the allotted time and when he checksout the platform keeps some of the customers amount as application fee and transfers the rest to the service provider,in this case the hotel.

**Current Effort:**

I Used `STRIPE CONNECT` to acheive the required functionality.

(`Note`: you guys don't need to see all of the code below just the heading and description would give you an idea of what i have done and what i'm trying to ask,but please do read the **issue** section)

i create a `Connect account` for the seller when he signs up on my Website

**Create Connect Account**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
  router.post("/createAccount", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email } = req.body; //Data Passed from the FrontEnd
  stripe.accounts.create(
    {
      type: "custom",
      country: "US",
      email: email,
      requested_capabilities: ["card_payments", "transfers"],
    },
    function (err, account) {
      res.json({ account: account });
    }
  );
});
```

When the Seller Provides the rest of the required details(including bank Account) after logging-in to the `Seller Portal` i create a `bank_account`,update the already created `Connect Account` and link the `bank_account` with the `Connect Account` (Hopefully, that somehow makes sense)

**Create Bank Account**

```
  router.post("/createBankAccount", async (req, res) => {
  const { account_holder_name, routing_number, account_number } = req.body;
  stripe.tokens.create(
    {
      bank_account: {
        country: "US",
        currency: "USD",
        account_holder_name,
        account_holder_type: "individual",
        routing_number,
        account_number,
      },
    },
    function (err, token) {
      res.send(token);
    }
  );
});
```

**Update Account:**

```
  router.post("/updateAccount", async (req, res) => {
      const {
        AccountID,
        Day,
        Month,
        Year,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        email,
        BankAccountID,
      } = req.body;

      const FrontFilePath = fs.readFileSync("PathToFileHere");
      const FrontPhotoIDUpload = await stripe.files.create({
        file: {
          data: FrontFilePath,
          name: "FrontPhotoID.jpg",
          type: "application.octet-stream",
        },
        purpose: "identity_document",
      });

      const BackFilePath = fs.readFileSync("PathToFileHere");
      const BackPhotoIDUpload = await stripe.files.create({
        file: {
          data: BackFilePath,
          name: "BackPhotoID.jpg",
          type: "application.octet-stream",
        },
        purpose: "identity_document",
      });

      stripe.accounts.update(
        AccountID,
        {
          business_type: "individual",
          individual: {
            dob: { day: Day, month: Month, year: Year },
            first_name: first_name,
            last_name: last_name,
            id_number: "006-20-8311",
            phone: "605-628-6049",
            address: {
              city: "Half Way",
              line1: "2467  Twin House Lane",
              postal_code: "65663",
              state: "MO",
            },
            email,
            ssn_last_4: "8311",
            verification: {
              document: {
                front: FrontPhotoIDUpload.id,
                back: BackPhotoIDUpload.id,
              },
            },
          },
          business_profile: {
            mcc: "4722",
            url: "http://www.baoisne.com",
          },
          tos_acceptance: {
            date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
            ip: req.connection.remoteAddress, 
          },
        },
        function (err, account) {
          console.log(err);
          console.log(account);
        }
      );
     //Connect External Account
      stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(
        AccountID,
        {
          external_account: BankAccountID,
        },
        function (err, bankAccount) {
          console.log(err);
          res.send(bankAccount);
        }
      );
    });
```

Then when the customers provides his account details i charge the customer,keep some money as application fee and move the rest to the Service Providers Connect account.

**Charge Customer**

```
  router.post("/charge", async (req, res) => {
  const { TokenID, CustomerID, Amount, AccountID } = req.body;
  let PaymentAmount = Amount * 100;
  let application_fee_amount = 400;
  try {
    const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: PaymentAmount,
      currency: "USD",
      description: "We did it boss",
      payment_method_data: {
        type: "card",
        card: {
          token: TokenID,
        },
      },
      receipt_email: "abdullahabid427@gmail.com",
      customer: CustomerID,
      application_fee_amount,
      transfer_data: {
      destination: AccountID,
      },
      confirm: true,
    });
    return res.status(200).json({
      confirm: "Payment Succeeded",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      message: error.message,
    });
  }
});
```

By doing the above procedure a connect account is created and the amount is moved into the connected account.

> **Issue**

The Above procedure although works correctly, it moves the amount into the Connected Service Provider Account directly after the customer is charged, what i would like is for the customer to pay the platform and after the Service Provider has provided his services , the Platform pays the Service Provider, i thought about removing

```
  application_fee_amount,
  transfer_data: {
  destination: AccountID,
  }
```

the above parameters in the `Charge` or `Stripe.paymentIntents.create` endpoint, and after Service Provider has completed his services i transfer the amount using the Stripe Transfer API

```
router.post("/transfer", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("TRANSFER=");
    const { AccountID, amount } = req.body;
    const transfer = await stripe.transfers.create({
      amount,
      currency: "USD",
      destination: AccountID,
    });
    res.send(transfer);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
});
```

the issue here is that transfer endpoint returns "*Your destination account needs to have at least one of the following capabilities enabled: transfers, legacy_payments*" , i have checked the Connected Account in Stripe Dashboard and in the Capabilities section `Card_Payment` and `Transfers` are both set to Active, plus Payments and Payouts are both Enabled and the status of the connect account is "Complete"

So if anyone could point in the right direction i would really Appreciate it,Cheers :)

Comment: The problem is likely that your code is transferring funds before the account's capabilities are enabled. You should switch the order to create the account and get it fully enabled first. Also, you don't have to do all of those separate API requests like that. You can pass all the information in one go on account creation directly in one request. This will make your code a lot easier to reason with. Ultimately, after the account is verified you need to wait for the capabilities to be active before you charge or transfer.

Comment: `You should switch the order to create the account and get it fully enabled first.` i couldn't quite get that,would you please elaborate , does the capabilities section in the dashboard or in the account object not specify if the capabilities are set or not ?,(Since it set to `active` when i checked) . `after the account is verified you need to wait for the capabilities to be active before you charge or transfer` , is there a way to somehow check that ?, if you could point in the right direction i would really appreciate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok - we'll agree that Stripe works as intended. You get the error message that you get because you remove the destination account ID from the payment intent creating function. That's where the problem lies, under your heading **Charge Customer**.

Let's look at it: (a shortened version)

```
const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: PaymentAmount,
  currency: "USD",
  ...
  customer: CustomerID,
  application_fee_amount,
  transfer_data: {
    destination: AccountID,
  },
  confirm: true,
});
```

The last property `confirm: true` is equivalent to creating and confirming the payment intent in the same call. The default value is `false` -- using that the status of the newly created payment intent will be `requires_confirmation`. And when you're ready, you confirm the payment intent along these lines:

```
const confirmedPayment = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(
    'payment_intent_id',
    {payment_method: 'card'},
    function(err, paymentIntent) {

    }
});
```

**A few general comments on things going wrong**

When a payer pays money for some goods online, it is the responsibility of the app developer to implement the logic, according to which the money and goods are sent and received: it can be prepaid, postpaid, or partially both. No logic is foolproof. In general, if we worry about customers taking advantage of our payment policy, we can require everything to be prepaid by all paying parties and include a fair refund policy. In this case, Stripe supports refunds of payment intents but what's more important: it keeps track of the status of the payment.

When the payment intent is created but not confirmed, the status is `requires_confirmation`. Not much can go wrong there. But after the payment intent has been confirmed, the status will be `processing` - this may take days. You may decide to cancel the payment at any time. But if things go fine, the status will change to `succeeded` which means that the funds are in the destination account. But if the payment fails for whatever reason, the status will return to `requires_payment_method`. Even in this case, there's no need to create a new payment or transfer object. You can retrieve the payment intent any time by calling `stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret)` and check the status. But in my opinion, it's much easier to monitor the status changes with a webhook that is configured to receive the status changing events. Even if no action takes place immediately when the status changes, we can store the status in the DB where it's available.

From experience, I've seen how common it is for payments to fail. It doesn't mean that there's any fraud going on on either side but it does mean that the app should be prepared to handle both cases. The events to add to the webhook config are `payment_intent.succeeded` and `payment_intent.payment_failed`. How these events are handled is specific to each and every application.

Comment: so i remove the `confirm` parameter from `stripe.paymentIntents.create` and instead of using the Transfer API i just confirm the payment intent, is that correct ? and will creating the payment intent charge the customer before confriming?

Comment: That's correct. The funds are not transferred until the payment intent is confirmed but they are transferred when the payment intent is confirmed. No need to create a transfer object.

Comment: wouldn't this fail in a real-life scenario tho?, e.g if the customer does not have enough amount, when the service provider has provided his services , the transaction would fail

Comment: Many things can go wrong no matter how you implement it. You'll get the result to your webhook if you want (succeeded/failed) but maybe you should ask a new question about that?

Comment: i understand that but i believe that it's my responsibility to figure out a way that it doesn't , this seems to be major loophole that the customers could exploit

Comment: If you can figure out a way that nothing goes wrong, you'll be very very rich. Think of the case of a restaurant: do you want the customer to pay before or after eating? Both policies are common, and either way, things can go wrong. In my opinion, it is your responsibility to be prepared to handle the case when things go wrong. Trying hard to avoid problems might be safer - but not really better. Who wants to enter a coffee shop protected by an army of soldiers and armored vehicles? Only to meet the shopkeeper who doesn't trust you, or any other customer?

Comment: To conclude: verify and store the customer id's. Stripe already does this. It works.

Comment: i understand what you are trying to say and i already have the customer details attached with charge , the issue is that the customer can easily have it both ways i.e enjoy the stay at the hotel and not pay for it,since i plan to have a contract with those hotels so it would be my responsibility to pay for the loss. i personally wanted to charge the customer first rather than at the end because i  haven't seen a system where you are charged at the end for the service you have acquired.so the initial plan was to charge the customer and pay the seller,Refund if something goes wrong

Comment: Looks like @koopajah was right, the account doesn't have the required capability when i make the transfer, it needs a few minutes , everything works perfectly as it is. just need to wait until the required capabilities are enabled. Thank you Miro for the answer,i appreciate the dedication :)

Answer (score -1):

Create a webhook (Stripe config) which includes:

- Events sent to the webhook: in this case `customer.created`, `customer.source.created`, `customer.source.updated`
- URL = the route that handles the events when they arrive

So you need to store the pending payment in your DB first. Then in the webhook, find it in the DB and complete the transfer.

Comment: I don't have much idea about webHooks but from what i know it's an endpoint which can send requests to my application. Also the webhook would respond according to the event , i don't want to transfer the amount when the customer is created or upadated. i would like to transfer the amount when the Service Provider has provided his services, e.g the time for the rented room in the hotel is over, the Platform pays the hotel. ( if i am wrong or if i am missing something please do let me know because i couldn't quite understand your answer fully)

Comment: Sorry I overlooked the details in your question and thought it was an issue people mentioned in the comments. I'll post a new one (but you might end up needing webhooks anyway)